# EventHandler that fires when the connection status of an outook changes

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am working on an Outlook Add-in using VSTO & C#. I need an event handler that fires when the connection status of an outook changes (*i.e. from online mode to offline and vice versa*). Is that possible? And is there such an event handler?

I've been searching alot on the net, but unfortunately I found nothing. I would really appreciate if anyone have insight on that or even a possible solution.

N.B: The outlook that I am using is Outlook 2007.

Comment: Might be out of luck... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/a6937948-d386-4029-8ced-93173580d55a/

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that triggers when Exchange goes offline or back online. See [MSDN forum reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsto/thread/7bd6b249-b5c9-4263-9006-e68c64d19ec1).

The best you can do is detect the current Exchange connectivity mode via [`Application.Session.ExchangeConnectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.exchangeconnectionmode.aspx). See [related forum post](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=6794).