# Outlook Events not firing when Exchange loses connectivity

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

We recently noticed an issue with **Outlook 2007** eventing that causes it to not trigger events when Exchange connectivity is lost and then recovered. If you [attach a listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx) to [`Folder.Items.ItemAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event.itemadd.aspx) event, the event will get disconnected after Exchange toggles from offline to online. To reproduce this - we removed our ethernet cable in and out to simulate a brief connection loss.

This really makes it hard to build plugins if you can't guarantee events will be triggered when the Exchange connectivity has had an outage - especially common when operating from a remote office. We are not using cached exchange mode.

Does anyone have any feedback on whether their is a workaround, or how to know when we need to re-establish our event listener? Is using **cached exchange mode** a solution?
Or are there [certain events which you just can't use reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733926/making-items-itemadd-event-a-sturdy-option-for-firing-incoming-emails-even-whe)?

There [doesn't appear to be an event trigger for when Exchange connectivity is lost](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsto/thread/7bd6b249-b5c9-4263-9006-e68c64d19ec1). Maybe the only workaround here is using some sort of timer for reliable eventing behavior.

```cs
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  Outlook.Items sentItems;      
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    Outlook.Folder sentFolder = ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    sentItems = sentFolder.Items;
    sentItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(SentItems_ItemAdd);
  }
  void SentItems_ItemAdd(object Item)
  { // breakpoint never hit after Exchange connectivity is lost
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After troubleshooting this problem, it was discovered **there are certain events that are not re-established after you lose connectivity with Exchange**. Events such as [`Application.Explorers.NewExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorersevents_event.newexplorer.aspx) and [`Application.Inspectors.NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx) are not affected by Exchange connectivity, but [`Folder.Items.ItemAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event.itemadd.aspx) is. Perhaps this is due to  [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder_members.aspx)'s inheritance of [`MAPIFolder.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.items.aspx).

The only solution to re-establishing the event triggers is to periodically reconnect the events (*[since we don't have an event to tell us when Exchange is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6072757/175679)*) or re-attach the events during user-initiated actions such as [`NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx) or [`MailItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send.aspx).

[MSDN Forums recommends you don't use the `ItemAdd` event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/outlookdev/thread/74f61f85-8db7-408b-97b5-5e50deb42776) as only intended to be used via the UI.